# Python indent output different for same code format

Tags: python-3.x, indentation

I have 2 codes with similar format but the "return value" need to be indented differently to get the correct answer, but I am not sure why this is happening. Explanations will be appreciated, thanks!

Code: 1

```
def get_recession_start():
    '''Returns the year and quarter of the recession start time as a 
    string value in a format such as 2005q3
    A recession is defined as starting with two consecutive quarters of GDP decline, 
    and ending with two consecutive quarters of GDP growth.'''

    gdp = pd.read_excel('gdplev.xls', skiprows=220, header=None)
    gdp = gdp[[4,6]]
    gdp.columns = ['Quarter', 'GDP in billions' ]
    for i in range(len(gdp)):
        if (gdp.iloc[i-2][1] > gdp.iloc[i-1][1]) and (gdp.iloc[i-1][1] > gdp.iloc[i][1]):
            start = gdp.iloc[i-3][0]  
    return start
```

I get the correct answer for code 1, but when I try doing it for code 2 I get the wrong answer:

```
def get_recession_end():
    '''Returns the year and quarter of the recession end time as a 
    string value in a format such as 2005q3'''

    gdp = pd.read_excel('gdplev.xls', skiprows=220, header=None)
    gdp = gdp[[4,6]]
    gdp.columns = ['Quarter', 'GDP in billions' ]
    start = get_recession_start()
    start_index = gdp[gdp['Quarter'] == start].index.tolist()[0]
    gdp = gdp.iloc[start_index: ]
    for i in range(len(gdp)):
        if (gdp.iloc[i-2][1] < gdp.iloc[i-1][1]) and (gdp.iloc[i-1][1] < gdp.iloc[i][1]):
            end = gdp.iloc[i][0]                
    return end
```

I have to indent the return value like so to get the correct answer, but am not sure why since the if statement is basically the same as code 1 and I am trying to return the end variable just like I did with the start variable:

```
def get_recession_end():
    '''Returns the year and quarter of the recession end time as a 
    string value in a format such as 2005q3'''

    gdp = pd.read_excel('gdplev.xls', skiprows=220, header=None)
    gdp = gdp[[4,6]]
    gdp.columns = ['Quarter', 'GDP in billions' ]
    start = get_recession_start()
    start_index = gdp[gdp['Quarter'] == start].index.tolist()[0]
    gdp = gdp.iloc[start_index: ]
    for i in range(len(gdp)):
        if (gdp.iloc[i-2][1] < gdp.iloc[i-1][1]) and (gdp.iloc[i-1][1] < gdp.iloc[i][1]):
            end = gdp.iloc[i][0]
            return end
```

Comment: The `if` statement looks the same but the value assignments of `start` and `end` are different, the `gdp` thingy is also different so that might be the cause

Comment: Hello, I am not sure I understand since both codes are iterating through the list to find the value of i? I looked more closely at the list for code 2, without the indent for return, it gave me the last value of the list. But when I do the indent, it iterate through the list just fine. If that is the case, then I just don't get why code 1 iterated fined without the indent return.